# Why do I get a string format error in a Create view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following view model:

```
public class BetViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Bet Name")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be {2) characters or less.")]
    public string BetName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be greater than zero.")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I pass this to a `Create` view, with `@model PayCaddy.Client.Models.BetViewModel`, I get an `Input string was not in a correct format.` exception on the 'EditorFor' `BetName` line, in the view model mentioned above:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BetName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BetName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BetName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course `BetName` is null; this is a `Create` operation. The only other info I can give is how I map the view model:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var bet = new Bet();
    bet.Owner = GetApplicationUser();
    var model = Mapper.Map<BetViewModel>(bet);
    return View(model);
}
```

I have never come across anything like this in years. BTW, I am trying to make this a switchable desktop browser/mobile app, using `jQuery.Mobile`, but I have nothing mobile enabled yet - it should function as a normal desktop app.

Comment: Razor does not always report the correct line of the error and I suspect you error is actually somewhere else in your view. What happens if you just comment out `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BetName, ..)`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It works fine if I comment out `BetName`.

Comment: Ahh, You error message string is incorrect - `{2)` should be `{2}` (but I thing you want `{1}` anyway)

Comment: Yes, answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a error in the `ErrorMessage` string - `{2)` should be `{2}`, but if your wanting the message to read *BetName must be 100 characters or less.*, then it should be `{1}`

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be {1} characters or less.")]
public string BetName { get; set; }
```